# Regex that can accept 7-8 mobile number without "+"

Tags: regex, sitecore

I am using sms/mms field in sitecore for my mobile field but i already have a selection of prefix with this i need to discard the + sign on the field i have tried to use regex \d{7,8} but it seems it still accepts + sign.

Can anyone have a regex that will not accept the + sign[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWcsg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\d{7,8}$
```

^ and $ indicate the beginning and ending of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex - `/^[0-9]{7, 8}$/`

`^` indicates that your match begins at the start of the string
`[0-9]` indicates that you want to match only digits
`{7, 8}` indicates that you want to match only 7 or 8 digits
`$` indicates that your match ends at the end of the string